# How to synchronize this model correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading

Imagine there is a masseur and he has his own salon. He is sleeping the whole day until a customer enters the salon and wakes him up.

The customer is sleeping while he gets his massage. When the masseur finishes he wakes up the customer and gets paid for his service.

The customer leaves the salon.

The masseur enters the waiting room to look for another waiting (sleeping) customer. If there aren't any the masseur goes to bed again.

This is an interesting situation when working with threads.

```
public class Aufg1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MassageSalon ms = new MassageSalon();
        Customer c = new Customer(ms);
        Masseur m = new Masseur(ms);
        m.start(); c.start();
    }
}
```

**Masseur.java**

```
public class Masseur extends Thread{

    final MassageSalon salon;

    public Masseur(MassageSalon pSalon){
        salon = pSalon;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            salon.getNextCustomer();
            salon.finishedMassage();
        }
    }
}
```

and **Customer.java**:

```
public class Customer extends Thread{

    final MassageSalon salon;

    public Customer(MassageSalon pSalon){
        salon = pSalon;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
            salon.getMassage();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class MassageSalon. The code describes pretty much the same I just mentioned.

Now I want to use `wait(), notify(), notifyAll()` to ensure that everything works just like I mentioned it. I already edited the MassageSalon class and added wait(), notify() methods.

Do you think the positions for wait() and notify() are correct? When running this code the finishedMassage method isn't called. Why?

```
 public class MassageSalon {
    private int customerOnCouch = 0;
    private int customerPaid = 0;
    private int masseurAvailable = 0;
    private int masseurBusy = 0;
    private int masseurDone = 0;
    private int masseurClose = 0;


    public synchronized void getNextCustomer() {

        while(masseurAvailable != masseurClose){
            try{
                System.out.println("waiting for masseur...");
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        //masseur is available to handle a new customer

        System.out.println("masseur is available to handle a new customer");

        masseurAvailable++;

        while(customerOnCouch == customerPaid){
            try{
                System.out.println("waiting for customer...");
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        //and is busy as soon as a new customers takes his couch

        System.out.println("and is busy as soon as a new customers takes his couch");

        masseurBusy++;
    }

    public synchronized void finishedMassage() {
        //eventually the masseur finishes the massage

        System.out.println("eventually the masseur finishes the massage");

        masseurDone++;

        notify();

        //and closes the deal as soon as the customer paid

        System.out.println("and closes the deal as soon as the customer paid");

        masseurClose++;
    }

    public synchronized void getMassage() {
        //customer takes a couch

        System.out.println("customer takes a couch");

        customerOnCouch++;  

        notify();

        while(masseurBusy != masseurDone){
            try{
                System.out.println("waiting to finish massage");
                wait();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

        //and pays for the massage after it

        System.out.println("and pays for the massage after it");

        customerPaid++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rom1: yes, it's [Dijkstra's sleeping-barber problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing Dijkstra's Sleeping-Barber problem, but with a massage salon instead of a barber shop. The solution remains the same, though, and can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem#Solution

Comment: well it's not exactly the same. I just want to know where to put wait, notfiy and notifyAll in the above code to have mutual exclusion.

Comment: @ArtWorkAD. Lots of things are missing. You need to create threads and some kind of queue of customers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a fair [Semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) called NotSleeping.

As long as the customer does not enter the saloon, it holds NotSleeping. When customer comes in, it releases the semaphore, which wakes the thread of the masseur trying to grab NotSleeping too. After release, customer tries to hold NotSleeping again during the massage.

When done, Masseur releases NotSleeping, which is grabed again by the customer. Masseur, tries to hold NotSleeping again, until customer comes in. Etc Etc...